# On an HTML form with two buttons, how can I get one button to submit the form and the other one not?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

See the example below using ReactJS for brevity.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => alert('form submitted');}>
    <input id="text1"/>
    <input id="text2"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onClick={(e) => alert('button clicked, please don't submit!!!')}>Don't Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the above example what I would like to have is so that when the *Submit* button is clicked the alert "form submitted" is shown and when the *Don't Submit* button is clicked the user should see the "button clicked, please don't submit!!!" alert without begin followed by the "Submit" alert. Additionally neither of these buttons should cause an actual true form submission to post back to the server. So far I'm tried every way to prevent submit from occurring such as `e.preventDefault()` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you don't want either button to cause an actual form submit, can you change the button type for the first button? I'm not sure how you plan to execute the actual form submit, but I assume it submits right now when you click the first button.

Comment: By default, a `<button type="button">` will not submit your form.

Answer (score 4):

Check this:

```
<form onsubmit="alert('form submitted');">
    <input id="text1"/>
    <input id="text2"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('button clicked, please don\'t submit!!!')">Don't Submit</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81kx5otf/1/

Here the button type submit shows an alert with 'form submitted' message, and the button type button shows 'button clicked, please don't submit!!!'.

**For ReactJS**

```
render: function(){

    function onsubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      alert('form submitted');
    }

    function myfunc(){
      alert('button clicked, please don\'t submit!!!');
    }

    return (

        <form onSubmit={onsubmit}>
            <input id="text1" />
            <input id="text2" />
            <button type="submit">{"Submit"}</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={myfunc}>{"Don't Submit"}</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your fiddle but the second button did nothing for me. I'm using Chrome... didn't look any further yet though.

Comment: @jpierson I'm sorry, I had a bug in my code for a quotation mark, verify again please.

Comment: Hmm, this is the same as what I had without the ReactJS stuff. Is my issue specific to React then?

Comment: It could be. Check my code again, I just add an example with reactjs.

Comment: There must be something else wrong in my code. I'm basically doing the same thing as in your example but I'm not getting the same behavior. If I can boil it down to something else I'll credit your answer.

Comment: In your example you are using another way. Use my code, not yours (you are using "(e) => ... "), for verify. Maybe you will need paste here all your code for we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {if (e.target.id === 'sub') {alert('form submitted');}}}>
<input id="text1"/>
<input id="text2"/>
<button id="sub" type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="button" onClick={(e) => alert('button clicked, please don't submit!!!')}>Don't Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into this option. Reminds me of some examples I've seen around for using the value or name attributes when actually submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way

your form:

```
<form id="form" >
    <input id="text1"/>
    <input id="text2"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="alert('Don\'t Submit')">Don't Submit</button>
</form>
```

Little script:

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById("form")
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("submitting")
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found one solution that works however it avoids using the form's submit directly which from what I can recall gets rid of some of the form niceties related to validation and automatic Enter key support and such.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault();}>
    <input id="text1"/>
    <input id="text2"/>
    <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => alert('form submitted');}>Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onClick={(e) => alert('button clicked, please don't submit!!!')}>Don't Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would prefer a solution that still makes use of the form's onSubmit method without actually submitting the form though. Using *ngForm* I remember having a real nice behavior that I guess I'm trying to replicate. Benvorth's solution may give me more of what I'm looking for in this regard.